# Remove meeting workspace creation by using visual studio 2010?

Tags: 2010

I have read a couple of blogs and post that this is possible with sharepoint designer updating some aspx pages for the events list.
However we need this to be easily deployable with a visual studio solution.

The exact questions is: how can I disable workspace meeting creation from a visual studio solution?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by hiding the WorkspaceLink field from the Calendar list. If you have existing calendars, you can create a Feature with an event receiver that iterates through all calendars and runs the following code:

```
SPWeb web = //get the SPWeb object from somewhere
SPList list = web.Lists["CalendarName"];
var field = list.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkspaceLink];
field.Hidden = true;
field.Update();
```

If you want all new calendar to work like this, you need to create a feature that provision a new calendar. Look at http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/04/26/how-to-remove-workspace-link-from-a-calendar/ for how to do that.